# how to set compatibility of IOS on app

Tags: iphone, deployment, binary, version, ios4

I just submitted my app for distribution, when it showed the following message:
"The binary uploaded for the latest version of this app indicates that iOS 4.3 or later is required. Apps that require iOS 4.3 or later will not be available to Verizon iPhone users. If this app could be compatible with earlier iOS versions, you may want to reject the binary and upload a new one that indicates the earliest compatible iOS."

I would like to make the app verizon compatible, if the process is quick.

If I just change the IOS deployment target on my project to 4.0, should it be ok?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should, if you haven't used some too recent features obviously.

Update: here's a checklist from the official docs of [what's new in iOS 4.x](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#releasenotes/General/WhatsNewIniPhoneOS/Introduction/Introduction.html)

- Game Center
- Printing
- AirPlay
- Various enhancements (iAd, Media player, etc...)

Answer (score 2):

It depends what frameworks and other features you are using with your app and whether they are compatible with iOS 4.0. If there are features not compatible, you might be able to disable them for earlier versions, using ["weak linking"](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/cross_development/Using/using.html). If possible, test your application on a device using an iOS version earlier than 4.3.